# HttpContext.User null with authenticated user?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

So I'm working on a .net core 2 project which where we want to create a basic platform which we can use for our future projects. For the login we use Identity. We have it all setup, the user can succesfully login and the cookie gets set. For some reason once we call HttpContext.User this results in a null. I'm pretty sure it does find an identity, yet this identity is empty. We have checked the cookie and it is perfectly fine, it has it's token. We did add token authentication, but that should not interfere with the cookie system when it sets the cookie.

Below is the Startup.cs

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MyIdentityDbContext>(options => options
        .UseSqlServer("Data Source=PATH;Initial Catalog=DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ID;Password=*******"));

        services.AddSingleton<IJwtFactory, JwtFactory>();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie();

        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider;
        })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyIdentityDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardClientCertificate = false;
        });

        var jwtAppSettingOptions = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(JwtIssuerOptions));

        services.Configure<JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Issuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
            options.Audience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)];
            options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        });

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)],

            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Audience)],

            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

            RequireExpirationTime = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };

        services
           .AddAuthentication(options =>
           {
               options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

           })
       .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
       {
           cfg.ClaimsIssuer = jwtAppSettingOptions[nameof(JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer)];
           cfg.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
           cfg.SaveToken = true;
       });

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

            // Lockout settings
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login"; // If the LoginPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Login
            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout"; // If the LogoutPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Logout
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied"; // If the AccessDeniedPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/AccessDenied
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Name = "MyAuthToken",
                Path = "/",
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
                SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest
            };
        });


        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("EmployeeOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Employee"));
            options.AddPolicy("OwnerOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Owner"));
            options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Admin"));
            options.AddPolicy("ModeratorOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Moderator"));
        });

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);

        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
    }
```

Here is the code used in the controller to get the user:

```
 User _user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

And the code we use to login the user:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email,
                    model.Password, true, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `AddAuthentication` two times, once for `Cookie` and once for `JWT` and override the defaults.

only use `AddAuthentication` once and add `Cookie` and `JWT` to it.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    // set schema here
})
.AddCookie(config =>
{
    //config cookie
})
.AddJwtBearer(config =>
{
    //config jwt
});
```

Now that you have two authentication scheme, you must select which one you want to authenticate your request with

`[Authorize(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

or

`[Authorize(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

or even both

`[Authorize($"{CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme},{JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}")]`

Comment: I might have been to quick marking this as the answer. So this works for the [Authorize] authentication. But my HttpContext.User is still returning null. I have set the default scheme to cookie authentication. It does find an identity, but it's properties are all null..

Comment: Did you find out?